# Why won't my custom ore feature generate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I have a custom feature defined in a datapack, as shown below. Whenever I change the field `Name` from `minecraft:cyan_wool` to `minecraft:lapis_ore`, the lapis blobs show up during world generation. However, if I change it back to cyan wool, the blobs won't generate. If I want to generate these custom wool blobs, can I do this just using a datapack, or do I have to create a mod?

```
{
  "feature": {
    "type": "minecraft:ore",
    "config": {
      "size": 6,
      "discard_chance_on_air_exposure": 0,
      "targets": [
        {
          "target": {
            "predicate_type": "minecraft:tag_match",
            "tag": "minecraft:stone_ore_replaceables"
          },
          "state": {
            "Name": "minecraft:cyan_wool"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "placement": [
    {
      "type": "minecraft:count",
      "count": 10
    },
    {
      "type": "minecraft:in_square"
    },
    {
      "type": "minecraft:height_range",
      "height": {
        "type": "minecraft:trapezoid",
        "max_inclusive": {
          "above_bottom": 64
        },
        "min_inclusive": {
          "above_bottom": -64
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```